Approximating solution of a second degree ODE
Consider the second-order DE $y'' + p(x) y = 0$, such that $\int_{}^{\infty} t|p(t)| dt < \infty$. Show that, for any solution $y(x)$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} y'(x)$ exists, and every nontrivial solution is asymptotic to $d_0x + d_1$ for some constants $d_0$ and $d_1$ not both zero.
How to solve this question? I can prove that if $p(x) \rightarrow \infty$ monotonically as $x \rightarrow \infty$. All solutions of the above ODE are bounded in $[x_0, \infty)$.

Are you sure it's $p(t)$ in the equation? Seems like it should be $p(x)$.

yeah, you are right, thanks, changed.

I think the following is a proof for that $\lim_{x \to \infty} y'(x)$ exists. Maybe you can continue with this.
W.l.o.g let $p$ and a solution $y$ be defined on $[1,\infty)$. Integrating twice yields
$$
(\ast) \quad \quad y(x)=c_1+c_2 x - \int_1^x (x-t)p(t)y(t)dt
$$
for some constants $c_1,c_2$. Now for $x\ge 1$:
$$
|y(x)| \le (|c_1|+|c_2|)x + x \int_1^x |p(t)||y(t)|dt.
$$
Division by $x$ gives
$$
\frac{|y(x)|}{x} \le |c_1|+|c_2| +  \int_1^x |p(t)||y(t)|dt = |c_1|+|c_2| +  \int_1^x t|p(t)|\frac{|y(t)|}{t}dt.
$$
Now Gronwall's Lemma applied to the function $x \mapsto |y(x)|/x$ yields
$$
\frac{|y(x)|}{x} \le (|c_1|+|c_2|) \exp\left(\int_1^x t|p(t)| dt \right) \le c_3
$$
for some constant $c_3$ by convergence of $\int_1^\infty t|p(t)| dt$.
Deriving $(\ast)$ once gives
$$
y'(x)=c_2 - \int_1^x p(t)y(t)dt.
$$
Now we see that,
$$
\int_1^\infty p(t)y(t)dt
$$
is absolute convergent, since
$$
\int_1^x |p(t)||y(t)|dt = \int_1^x t|p(t)| \frac {|y(t)|}{t}dt \le c_3 \int_1^x t|p(t)| dt.
$$
Hence
$$
d_0:=\lim_{x \to \infty} y'(x)= c_2 -\int_1^\infty p(t)y(t)dt.
$$
For $d_1$ you should specify what exactly "$y$ is asymptotic to $d_0x+d_1$" means. Maybe $y(x)-d_0x$ has a limit $d_1$ as $x \to \infty$.
